# How can I uncompress a tar.xz thats been compressed on ubuntu and uncompress it on mac with the archive utility?

Tags: macos, mojave, tar, archive-utility

I have a file sent to me as a `file_name.tar.xz`file thats been compressed on ubuntu and I want to uncompress it on my mac. This isnt readily available out of the box so I looked up and installed a brew called `gnu-tar`.

I know that I can uncompress it on the terminal but I would like to use this with the archive utility on my mac.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can with archive utility but look at Unarchiver which is in the App Store https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archive Utility doesn't currently support .tar.xz files. You can provide feedback to Apple at [apple.com/feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html).

While Terminal can uncompress .tar.xz as you note, if you're looking for a GUI-based solution you can install:

### [<sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub> **The Unarchiver**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12&at=1001lwpF)

which has support for .tar.xz.

[image]